# get latitude longitude from marker and store to SQL database

Tags: php, sql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm making my final project
my project similiar to Salman's Latitude Longitude Finder Tool, but instead of showing the coordinate, i'll store the coordinate in SQL database using simple query.
because my lack of coding skill, i unable to do that, so anyone can help me?

what should i do next? 
and what variable that i must make?

here is the code straight from Salman's source

```
<form id="mapform" action="#">
<input id="mapinput" type="text" style="width: 80%;" value="Institut Teknologi Telkom, Sukapura, Dayeuhkolot, Bandung 40257, Indonesia" maxlength="100">
<input type="submit" style="width: 10%;" value="Find">
</form> 
<div id="mapdiv" style="height: 400px; width:90%"></div>
<div id="mapoutput" style="width:90%;background-color: #FFDD22; font-weight:      bold;">Latitude:<br>Longitude:</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?       v=3&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=AIzaSyAUQHXuw8OR1CzCPpo7bLMt_H_nauUHXKw"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {
//
// initialize map
//
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapdiv"), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng( -6.976801, 107.630835),
  zoom: 16,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
//
// initialize marker
//
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: map.getCenter(),
  draggable: true,
  map: map
});
//
// intercept map and marker movements
//
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
  marker.setPosition(map.getCenter());
  document.getElementById("mapoutput").innerHTML = "<a   href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent(map.getCenter().toUrlValue()) + "\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"float: right;\">Go to maps.google.com</a>Latitude: " + map.getCenter().lat().toFixed(6) + "<br>Longitude: " + map.getCenter().lng().toFixed(6);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function(mapEvent) {
  map.panTo(mapEvent.latLng);
});

//
// initialize geocoder
//
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("mapform"), "submit",      function(domEvent) {
  if (domEvent.preventDefault){
    domEvent.preventDefault();
  } else {
    domEvent.returnValue = false;
  }
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: document.getElementById("mapinput").value
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var result = results[0];
      document.getElementById("mapinput").value = result.formatted_address;
      if (result.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(result.geometry.viewport);
      }
      else {
        map.setCenter(result.geometry.location);
      }
    } else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
      alert("Sorry, the geocoder failed to locate the specified address.");
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, the geocoder failed with an internal error.");
    }
  });
  });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What's your problem?  The Javascript required to make the ajax request to store the coordinates; the PHP or the SQL needed to then save the coordinates in your DB?

Comment: i don't know how to use sql query alongside gmaps script variable, so i don't write any on code above, just the maps script

Answer (score 1):

Just edit `dragend` event of marker as

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
    var lat = this.getPosition().lat();
    var lng = this.getPosition().lng();
    //use an AJAX function to save the lat/lng to the data base
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:{latitude:lat, longitude:lng},
        url:"savecoords.php",
        success:function(response){
            if(reponse=="success"){
                alert('Location marked');
            }
            else{
                alert('Cant mark location');
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('An error occured');
        }
    });
});
```

In the AJAX function `lat` and `lng` are passed to the file `savecoords.php` thrugh variables `latitude` and `longitude` in `POST` method. In that file you can access the values as `$_POST['latitude']` and `$_POST['longitude']`. Then you need to create the `savecoords.php` file and the content must be like:

**savecoords.php**

```
<?php
    $latitude   =   $_POST['latitude'];
    $longitude  =   $_POST['longitude'];

    //establish mysqli connection

    $query      =   'Your save query with $latitude and $longitude';    
    if(mysqli_query($query)){
        echo "success";
    }
    else{
        echo "failed";
    }   
?>
```

Comment: so what is this AJAX function?

Comment: did you get the lat/lng in alert

Comment: yes i get it, so what should i do next?

Comment: you can use that value as you wish like `save` ..

Comment: okay i'll try to save into database

Comment: sorry but i think i don't know how to do that. sorry for my questions and my lack of programming skills

Comment: It is not a problem...can refer this link , https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ , to study what is an `AJAX` function and  how an AJAX function works

Comment: okay, thanks for your help. i'll contact you if need more help. how can i contact you?

Comment: make a chat if you want...

Comment: not enough reputation to chat :(

Comment: i found this solution from [here](http://kimjoyfox.com/ajax-jquery-and-form-submission/) and i understand a little bit. but my next question is what will be the php file is? because there is no explanation how do i processed the variable in the php file @sherin

Comment: @RizkyMuhammad..Could you save the lat/lng now..?

Comment: i'll try shortly, but is there a typo in php file? mysqli_query or mysql_query? @sherin

Comment: i think i need more help @sherin